# How do I see all the error in Vuelidate for troubleshooting purpose?

Tags: vuelidate

I am implementing Vuelidate in my Vue app. And this is my submit button html in pug.

```
button(@click="SUBMIT") Submit
```

And this is my SUBMIT method which I can debug.

```
async SUBMIT() {
  debugger
  this.$v.$touch();      
  if (this.$v.$invalid) {
    return;
  }
```

My problem is `this.$v.$invalid` is always true even though I think all my input pass validation. So my question is how do I see all the validation error when `this.$v.$invalid` is true? I want to use console.log to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.$v.$errors` to access the full list. In your code for example:

```js
async SUBMIT() {
  debugger
  this.$v.$touch(); 

  // Print a list of all errors
  console.log(this.$v.$errors)

  if (this.$v.$invalid) {
    return;
  }
```

In the documentation, [this section on collective properties](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/guide.html#collective-properties) I found useful for seeing what is available.